# HttpRequest times out

Tags: android, http, get, server

I'm trying to do a get request from my app to my computer using the format
`my_ip:8888/msg/my_message`
When I open the connection it works but the execution never gets past the execute(request) part. It times out (1 minute to) before it does the get request. The request url is correct because I've tried directly on my pc browser.
My android manifest has the internet permission.
Here's the code

```
    private static JSONObject sendPetition(HttpUriRequest request) throws Exception{
        AndroidHttpClient client;

        HttpResponse response;
        JSONObject responseJSON;

        client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("IPM-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE");
        response=  client.execute(request);
        responseJSON = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        client.close();
        return responseJSON;
    }
```

edit 1:

Seems like I haven't given enough info. sorry: this is the log

> 11-29 12:10:21.503    5546-5546/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente I/View﹕ Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Button{41f3ede0 VFED..C. ...P.... 311,754-407,826 #7f080002 app:id/button}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=59.31427, y[0]=32.06659, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=2125112, downTime=2124997, deviceId=4, source=0x1002 }
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.504    5546-5546/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente V/Provider/Settings﹕ from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.506    5546-5546/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=128KB
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.506    5546-5546/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.507    5546-5546/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.507    5546-5546/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.507    5546-5669/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12: interp stack at 0x6126a000
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.507    5546-5669/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12: created from interp
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.507    5546-5546/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.507    5546-5669/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12: notify debugger
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.507    5546-5669/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=12 (AsyncTask #1): calling run()
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.509    5546-5669/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente I/System.out﹕ httpget:http:// 192.168.0.8:8888/msg/play/eABHFSQKCdU
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.512    5546-5669/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente I/System.out﹕ http:// 192.168.0.8:8888/msg/play/eABHFSQKCdU
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.519    5546-5669/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ create interp thread : stack size=128KB
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.519    5546-5669/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ create new thread
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.519    5546-5669/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ new thread created
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.519    5546-5669/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ update thread list
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.519    5546-5670/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=13: interp stack at 0x6138a000
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.519    5546-5670/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=13: created from interp
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.519    5546-5669/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ start new thread
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.520    5546-5670/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=13: notify debugger
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.520    5546-5670/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=13 (RefQueueWorker@org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute@41fae950): calling run()
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.533    5546-5669/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente I/System.out﹕ [socket][0] connection /192.168.0.8:8888;LocalPort=34838(60000)
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.533    5546-5669/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente I/System.out﹕ [CDS]connect[/192.168.0.8:8888] tm:60
>
> 11-29 12:10:21.534    5546-5669/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente D/Posix﹕ [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente :8888

After that it just throws a connectiontimeout exception:

edit3:

> 11-29 12:27:19.988    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /192.168.0.8:8888 timed out
>
> 11-29 12:27:19.990    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
>
> 11-29 12:27:19.991    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
>
> 11-29 12:27:19.992    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>
> 11-29 12:27:19.992    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>
> 11-29 12:27:19.993    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
>
> 11-29 12:27:19.994    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:587)
>
> 11-29 12:27:19.995    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:511)
>
> 11-29 12:27:19.996    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:489)
>
> 11-29 12:27:19.996    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:260)
>
> 11-29 12:27:19.997    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at com.example.alvarofeal.model.Model.sendPetition(Model.java:29)
>
> 11-29 12:27:19.998    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at com.example.alvarofeal.model.Model.playVideo(Model.java:38)
>
> 11-29 12:27:19.999    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente.VideoList$Videos.doInBackground(VideoList.java:170)
>
> 11-29 12:27:20.000    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente.VideoList$Videos.doInBackground(VideoList.java:165)
>
> 11-29 12:27:20.003    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>
> 11-29 12:27:20.005    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>
> 11-29 12:27:20.007    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>
> 11-29 12:27:20.009    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>
> 11-29 12:27:20.012    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>
> 11-29 12:27:20.013    6207-6277/com.example.alvarofeal.aplicacioncliente W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Setup:
I'm using my android device and I'm trying to comunicate to my computer (port 8888). They are both in the same network.

Comment: Can you post you `AndroidHttpClient` class?

Comment: @rom4ek it's imported android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;

Comment: `using the format`. Please tell exactly the url you use. Your code is not very usefull to debug this problem as the actions involved are hidden. If there is a timeout you will have exceptions or errors mentioned in the logcat. Please post.

Comment: `When I open the connection it works`. What do you mean by that? What works?

Comment: @greenapps Added the log so you can see the url and waht's going on in the app.

Comment: `After that it just throws a connectiontimeout exception`. Thats what we want to see in the logs ofcourse! Please explain your setup. You have your local server i see. Where? Android client is running where? Emulator/device?

Comment: @greenapps aded exception logtrace and setup. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: `I've tried directly on my pc browser.`. Please try with browsers on your device.

Comment: @greenapps doesn't work... I'm guessing my pc is refusing the connection or something ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should setting the timeout to your request, like this:

```
   private static JSONObject sendPetition(HttpUriRequest request) throws Exception{
        AndroidHttpClient client;
        int timeout = 5000

        HttpResponse response;
        JSONObject responseJSON;

        client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("IPM-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE");

        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, timeout);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeout);

        request.setParams(httpParams);

        response = client.execute(request);
        responseJSON = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        client.close();
        return responseJSON;
    }
```

Comment: I've already tried... I think it's not a code problem, because I can't evend send the request using the device browser

Comment: So I think there is a server-side problem, not an Android. You should create another answer with your server code.

Comment: Yes, at first I didn't know that that's why I posted this.